# "INSTALL_FAILED_ABORTED: User rejected permissions" when installing apk from storage on Android 12

Tags: adb, installation, apk, android-12

> Edit: I notice this error when installing split apks using custom app installer from storage. But now I found this error also occurs when installing normal .apk file (I didn't notice this because I am using Android's default package installer). However .apk could be installed successfully(at least it seems like).

There is [a .xapk file in apkpure](https://apkpure.com/calendar-ai-planner-agenda/me.sync.syncai) and [here is the corresponding app on play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.sync.syncai).

I can install it using play store. But other approaches of installing this app failes(SAI_v4.5 and other installers), and about 20MB(the size of the .xapk file) is lost after installation failure.

I got the error

> INSTALL_FAILED_ABORTED: User rejected permissions

when installing split APKs (.xapk) on my Oppo Reno4 SE 5G running Android 12.

<sup>[Device spec from "About device"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVSXa.jpg)</sup>

```
# example commands to install split apks
pm install-create
pm install-write 18911812 base.apk /data/local/tmp/base.apk
pm install-write 18911812 split_1.apk /data/local/tmp/split_1.apk  
pm install-write 18911812 split_1.apk /data/local/tmp/split_1.apk  
pm install-commit
```

I tried to install it using ADB, and although `pm install-commit` returns with a `Success` message, the app is not fully installed. When using ADB, "Verify app over USB" is turned off.

How to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. According to [this thread (Chinese)](https://www.cnblogs.com/tianma3798/p/11378035.html), try disabling "Verify apps over USB" from the Developer options. There's also a mention of [enabling permission to install apps](https://forums.gamesalad.com/discussion/comment/615913/#Comment_615913), though I'm not sure about ADB. Otherwise, could you mention the device model? There's a mention of [MIUI putting the restriction on the newer Package Installer app](https://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/22-9-29.66978/post-672105).